# NativeWind and TailWind in React Native Expo does not work when wrapped in Navigation Container

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, tailwind-css

Nativewind work's perfectly when components are not wrapped in the a Navigation Container, but then when they are, the styles stop working. Yes, I have already tried restarting the server and clearing my cache with "expo start -c" but that does not work. For example -

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text className="font-extrabold">
        Hello
      </Text>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
           <Text className="font-extrabold">
              Hello
           </Text>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
```

The text outside the NavigationContaainer is being bolded, but not the text wrapped in the Navigation Container. I have tried using NVM to try different versions of node.js. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!